# Reflection to add/set new custom attributes

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to figure a way to add a new custom attribute at runtime, I realize this might be impossible so I will settle for adding the customer attribute normally bit I want to try to override/set the size

my class is this

```
Public Class POCO1

    <StringLength(15)>
    Property FirstName As String

    Property LastName As String

End Class
```

I would like to try something like

```
Dim lName As StringLengthAttribute = New StringLengthAttribute(50)

Dim last As PropertyInfo = this.GetProperty(("lastName")).Add(lName)
```

Comment: Is this for the purpose of applying different validation rules to a POCO?

Comment: The idea is to programmatically change the property so that I can limit the number if input characters from a WEBform. The entire form is generated from a Dataset (not my idea) , so 1 problem is that we have some small fields like middle name that are only 10 characters long and state is only 2 characters. I am trying to create a way to validate and throw back if what is input is too long

Comment: I would suggest looking at https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation which will allow you to parameterize your validation rules.